# Married man seducing a woman about to convert

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, sexuality

An Orthodox man seduces a woman in the process of converting, saying that he is separated from his wife while not yet divorced. He promises marriage to the woman converting and has relations with her.

What should be his punishment? Please include sources.

Comment: Why is this any different than someone who does that with someone who isn't Jewish but not about to convert?

Comment: Does that would not be a chilul Hashem, as the woman in question was deceived with false promises. Besides than this same woman could have its decision on the conversion and of Judaism itself influenced by this fact.

Comment: @moris Chillul Hashem is generally not punishable by earthly courts

Comment: So, it's right to do so?

Comment: No. It is something that is forbidden (besides the fact that relations with a nonJewish woman are forbidden in any case). There will be punishment from the heavenly court, but bais din does not have the authority any more to prescribe *malkus mardus* (lashes for rebellion) which bais din in the time of the talmud did have.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is not enough to make this same woman feel better.

Comment: @MorisK We're not going to lie to her. The guy who lied and cheated with her is a bum, scoundrel, criminal, fool, sinner, and overall bad, gross and offensive. Judaism does not condone his actions at all. He did the wrong thing. There is no way we try to justify it, and we all feel bad for her that someone did this horrible thing to her. Our courts as a policy don't have statutory punishments for every crime. That doesn't detract from the absolute definitive way we categorize his actions: Wrong. Every group has its rotten apples; I'm truly sorry she happen to run into such a rotten one so soon

Comment: @DoubleAA whew! This would be a wonderful answer if submitted so!

Comment: This man not only made a horrible thing but also shamed all klal Isroel.

Comment: @MorisK Yes. Very very bad. Terrible horrible no good very-bad guy. No one is denying that.

Answer (score 1):

DoubleAA's comment hit it on the head. As described here, the person is a bum and a scoundrel and likely gave our faith a bad name.

Today we don't do "punishments" like stockades or whippings or whatever -- and **you should not take matters into your own hands**; it's up to a local community to decide if it's worthwhile to publicize someone's malfeasance, deny them synagogue honors, or the like. (In a case like this I don't think that publicizing anything would make anything better, as angry as people may feel.)

(On an every-so-slightly related note: Rabbi Moshe Feinstein had a responsum sent to Bueno Aires about a woman studying for conversion who got pregnant from a single Jewish man she'd been seeing. The local rabbi blamed him, not her; and he sheepishly replied that he couldn't wait any longer. Rabbi Feinstein allowed the rabbi to have her convert and marry him, with one argument being that if he were to drop her, she'd go to the Argentine courts for child support, and that would be an even bigger disgrace to God's name. But at least in that case no one was cheating or lying.)